# Sending terminal commands from ssh-remote server back to local through ssh?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote-server, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to send terminal commands into my local Mac from my remote linux server. This is currently to generate
local notifications

```
(using terminal command: 
"""osascript -e 'display notification "Message" with title "Title" subtitle "Subtitle" sound name "chimp"')"""
```

for changes determined by my app running on the server, but I think, if I have this sorted, 
I might use this for other uses/sending/exchanging other commands too later. 
Currently, I ssh in the server in the first place. I dont fully understand this process as it was preconfigured on my 
system. Can someone explain how this can be achieved?

PS: it will be helpful to be able to keep my/local/receiver IP as a variable and use that variable, as I might have to do this with multiple systems or change my own ip sometime. Also, implementing a password protection so only my app/admin can change/use this channel will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script on your remote host that:

- SSH into your local machine
- executes the `osascript` command

But you need to configure it so that you don't have to enter a password when the script is SSH to your local machine. To make that work, you can copy the public SSH key of the user on the remote-host (maybe root) into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the user on your local machine.

On the remote host:

```
# copy the public key for the user on the remote host to the local host
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<your-local-machine> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Then write a script and save it on the remote host

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh <user>@<your-local-machine> osascript -e 'display notification "Message" with title "Title" subtitle "Subtitle" sound name "chimp"'
```

The program on your remote host can execute that script when it's appropriate.

If you need to SSH into a new machine, you'll have to copy the SSH keys again and change the `<your-local-machine>` address in the script.